# Batch Script For Loop to Websites with user input

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, alt-tab

I'd like to run a batch script on Windows that will prompt users for input (a list) that is then used to open up all the websites as tabs in one window (like a *for loop*) (not sure if this question belongs in superuser or the stackoverflow)

Pseudo code:

set variable `page` and give user prompt

`What websites would you like to go to?`

{ user will input a list of websites: `google yahoo aol youtube` }

for every word typed by the user,

`start chrome.exe -new-window "%page%".com`

Comment: Welcome to SU. Do I understand correctly: after user gives input on your script, Chrome is supposed to open in the background, not steal focus from the window the user is giving the input? Please don't answer in a comment, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777616/edit) your question instead to add new info. This improves the focus and keeps everything relevant immediately available.

Comment: SU is not a free script writing service.  We will *help you* but unlikely that anyone will *do it for you*.  I personally need to see more of your code than a single `set /p` line.

Comment: are you set on using a batch file or would a powershell script be acceptable? Batch cmd is a lot harder for this specific use case because splitting a user input string of unknown length is not trivial